# How can I disable the [Run...] main menu item in Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, terminal, security

I'm creating a build to be used by others in a company as a very simple remote dial-in tool to be used in emergencies.  I'm basing this on Pis Version 3 and above running on Buster.

The basic dial-in and setup I have working as I'd like, but I'd like to make this as fiddle and idiot proof as possible as it will be going out potentially to a wide and varied audience - I don't want my family to be getting woken up at 2am because someone messed up their machine by fiddling and now can't log on....

Does anyone know how I can remove the '*run...*' menu item from the main menu (and if at all possible disable [*Alt-F2*] as well.  This should prevent most people from messing about and getting to the terminal.

Any other advice around securing a pi to prevent local fiddling would be great - my plan is to have the user profile locked down and logged into automatically and have an admin account with a crazy password that can be logged into as required.  No sensitive data will be stored on the pi so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical - found the answer a few hours later whilst doing something else...

inside /home/[user]/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel *Plugin { type=menu....*

there are some lines:

```
  item {
    name=Run...
    image=system-run
    command=run
  }
```

removing these line, saving and rebooting removes the run menu item for that user.

now to disable [*Alt-F2*]....

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Cheers Ingo - noob on the forum and didn't know if accepting your own answers was a faux pas.  :)  will do

Comment: I don't have a panels subdirectory.  All I have is an autostart file (which I created).  Is there a sample of files in that directory that I can copy and modify?